# Any ways to maintain a custom DPI setting on a Logitech G400 mouse without the Gaming Software

Tags: windows-10, logitech-mouse

I'm on Windows 10. I use a Logitech G400 mouse.

This mouse allows for direct DPI changes through built-in toggle buttons. However none of the presets suit me, so I had to install the Logitech Gaming Software and set a comfortable DPI within the software.

This Gaming Software is quite cumbersome by itself (114 MB) and significantly increases system boot time. In addition, the software offers a large array of gaming-oriented features which I do not use.

I have tried to exit the software after it has loaded, or to boot with the software disabled. The mouse immediately defaults to its highest (fastest) DPI in both cases.

Is there a way to make the mouse remember, default to, or otherwise use my custom DPI without the Gaming Software?

Comment: The software can't just have run on startup disabled?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If I disable the Gaming Software in the startup options, my mouse uses the highest DPI by default, which for me is uncontrollably fast. If I start the Gaming Software afterwards, my mouse would use my custom DPI; if I then exit the software, my mouse reverts to the highest DPI.

Comment: Can you tell LGS to save the settings on the mouse itself?

Comment: I'd run [procmon.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and try to figure out what the LG software does to change the mouse's DPI setting and then do it myself. This [tutorial on using procmon.exe](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/sysinternals-pro/lesson5/) might help get you started.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't do this.**

For reasons known only to Logitech, The G400 (and perhaps more models) only has two native (hardware) DPI settings, being 1800 and 3600. The rest are *interpolated*.

The two other settings on this mouse, the 400 and 800 DPI, are interpolated internally by the mouse. Any other DPI you set are interpolated by the Logitech Gaming Software: the software intercepts the mouse movement, interpolates the DPI to the value you have chosen, *then* sends the movement information to the OS.

So the conclusion is: you either have to stick to the 4 presets if you don't want to use the software, or give up on your custom DPI and ditch the software. I get it, it's hard; I don't game either, but I bought this same mouse because I needed to be able to customize mouse sensitivity.